# Regex to match all strings with a trust list only

Tags: regex

I look to make a regex to match all strings that i have with a specific list of words, the string may be separated by ";" or "," or space wherever, and without order

example:

my list of trust: one two tree

```
if: one --> true

if: two + one --> true

if: one + tree + one --> true

if: four --> false

if: one + four --> false

if: one + two + tree + four --> false
```

the regex must no match when find at least one intruder out of the trust list, also the strings may be separated by ";" or "," or space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the following regex to match `one` `two` or `three` seperated by `;` `,` or `space`

```
/(^\s*(one|two|three)\s*$|(^\s*(one|two|three)([ ,;]+(one|two|three))+\s*$))/gm
```

Test more here: https://regex101.com/r/ETN5go/4

Comment: Thank you so much,
I'm not good in regex, can you please explain why i have to put a string 3 time to add it in the trust list ? also can i make it case insensitive ?

Comment: To make the pattern case insensitive, just use the **i** (insensitive) flag. So at the end of the pattern it would be /gmi

Comment: You repeat it three times because it has to cover every possible case. The first case is when there is only one word. The second group is for when it is a valid word followed by any number of other valid words.